# Standardized web progress

Tags: python, c#, task, status, completion

I have a web front end that triggers a long running server side process that travels through a bunch of micro services through message queuing. On a page, how can I display these processes and the percentage done of the running ones?

---

I've been doing some google searching to find out what the best way to do this but I'm seeing either nothing relevant or everyone rolling their own code to report statuses. I keep getting stuff for tracking and reporting project statuses as well which is not what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how best to accomplish this? Surely there are common libraries or techniques that people like using.

Language doesn't so much matter as technique. Though I am pretty fluent in C#, Java and Python so those will probably make the most sense.

Comment: Why do you need to track it at all?   It's an unusual question, which is probably why you are having difficulty finding an answer.  I have worked on many microservice architecture projects, and so far haven't come across this kind of requirement.  You could fire an event when the message has been processed in each microservice, but then, how do you know you've reached the end?

Comment: @Neil From what I understand, this is similar to Jenkins, for example, where it shows (an estimation) for how long each stage takes

Comment: Build pipelines generally have a fixed number of stages, whereas a microservice could have 1 or 1000 different stages, depending on the content of the message, and you wouldn't know up front, how many stages that particular message requires.

Comment: Currently the thing I'm working on is a rather large legacy monolith of code, hence the desire for microservices. Most of them will be just putting together the data but eventually there'll be one that actually does the calculation part.

I plan to do as much as I can in parallel. But even breaking it down, the calculation this thing is doing is still made up of massive sets of numbers being run through a convoluted algorithm. It's not unusual for the thing to take days to complete as it stands. 

If the user doesn't have any idea where in the process it is they're going to get impatient.